# Nomen + Adjektiv in Kombination mit Bindestrichen

Tags: adjective, capitalization, compound, hyphen

Hat man ein Adjektiv, welches im Kern aus einem Nomen besteht, dann wird das laut [Canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Komposition/A-Comp/Nomen%20A/N%20A.html) kleingeschrieben. @Takkat war im Chat schon so freundlich mir diesen Link zu posten. Er hat mich aber gleichzeitig darauf aufmerksam gemacht, dass bei [Adjektiven mit Bindestrichen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Nomen.html#Anchor-Nomen-11481) die Situation anders ist.

Demnach schreibt man also

> artefaktbehaftet

aber

> Amerika-freundlich

Nun will es der Zufall, dass mein Satz wie folgt lautet:

> Momentan extrahiere ich Informationen aus artefakt- und rauschbehafteten Experimentaldaten.

Frage: Wird nun "artefakt-" zu "Artefakt-" oder ist diese Regel hier außer Kraft gesetzt?

Comment: Verwandt: [Groß- und Kleinschreibung und Bindestrich bei Substantiv-Adjektiv-Zusammensetzungen](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20032/2594).

Comment: Es wäre übrigens auch zulässig, *amerikafreundlich* zu schreiben.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich hätte es genauso gesagt wie Takkat: der Eigenname Amerika erzwingt einen Bindestrich und die Großschreibung des ersten Buchstabens. Für `artefakt- und rauschbehaftet` gilt das nicht, da der Strich nach `artefakt` kein Binde-, sondern ein Trennstrich ist.

Answer (score 7):

Gerade bei horizontalen Strichen muss man in Sprachen, die das lateinische Alphabet verwenden, zwischen Aussehen und Funktion unterscheiden. Vom Aussehen bzw. typografisch geht es hier um den Viertelgeviertstrich¹, der im Deutschen für drei Funktionen genutzt wird:

- Als Bindestrich, um Wortfugen anzuzeigen, z. B. in *Amerika-freundlich, Fußball-Weltmeisterschaft, Castrop-Rauxel* oder *S-Kurve.*
- Als Trennstrich am Zeilenende, um anzuzeigen, dass das Wort in der nächsten Zeile fortgeführt wird.
- Als Ergänzungsstrich, um das in einer Aufzählung von Elementen mit gleichem Bestandteil einer ausgelassen wurde, z. B. in *Hoch- und Tiefbau; Glasfenster* und *-türen* oder eben *artefakt-* und *rauschbehaftet.*

Verwirrenderweise wird der Viertelgeviertstrich häufig generell als *Bindestrich* bezeichnet², aber die offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln trennen klar zwischen drei obigen Funktionen. Dadurch werden insbesondere durch das Setzen eines Ergänzungsstrichs keine Regeln, die den Bindestrich betreffen, “aktiviert”. Der Strich in *artefakt-* und *rauschbehaftet* ist eben ein Ergänzungsstrich und kein Bindestrich und deswegen liegt hier auch nicht plötzlich ein mit Bindestrich geschriebenes Adjektiv vor, dessen substantivische Bestandteile man großschreiben müsste.

---

<sup>¹ Der einem Strich entstammt, der ein viertel Geviert lang war, aber heute eine andere Länge haben kann – genauso wie der Halbgeviert- und Geviertstrich.

² genauso wie der Halbgeviertstrich häufig als *Gedankenstrich* bezeichnet wird, obwohl er auch als Bis-Strich, Streckenstrich o. Ä. fungieren kann.</sup>

Comment: +1 für die Differenzierung von Typografie und Funktion. Allerdings gelten auch die Bezeichnungen wie _Halbgeviertstrich_ in der Typografie nicht uneingeschränkt als glücklich, da dieser Strich gar nicht unbedingt ein halbes Geviert lang ist.

Comment: @Loong: Richtig, habe ich ergänzt. Immerhin ist den meisten typografischen Laien nicht auf Anhieb bewusst, wie lang ein Geviert ist.

Answer (score 1):

Hier wird unterschieden zwischen einem Bindestrich zur Verdeutlichung von Zusammenhängen

> Amerika-freundlich

und einem Bindestrich als Ergänzungsstrich.

> artefakt- und rauschbehafteten

Amerika ist zudem ein Nomen, wird also in allen Fällen großgeschrieben, außer es wird adjektiviert.

> amerikanisch

In deinem Beispielsatz heißt es also quasi:

> Momentan extrahiere ich Informationen aus artefaktbehafteten und rauschbehafteten Experimentaldaten.

Da dies allerdings redundant wäre, fügt man einen Bindestrich ein und streicht das erste "behafteten", um die Verständlichkeit zu steigern.

Comment: Warum nicht „Artefakt-behaftet“?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Man könnte in einem Satz ggf. Artefakt-behaftet schreiben, jedoch ist dies in dem Beispiel nicht der Fall. Während "Artefakt-behaftet" nicht falsch ist, bevorzugte der Author (und jeder Deutschlehrer mit dem ich bislang redete) die pure Adjektive form "artefaktbehaftet";

In dem Beispiel handelt es sich jedoch wie oben gesagt um einen Bindestrich als Ergänzungsstrich, der Satzbau würde nur mit einer kleinen Änderung noch Sinn ergeben:
"Artefakt- und Rausch-behafteten".
Die andere Variante wird lediglich bevorzugt.

Comment: Dann gibt es wohl die Regel, die der Fragesteller meinte, gar nicht. Das sollte dann ein wesentlicher Teil der Antwort sein, oder?

Comment: Die Regel gibt es, Amtliche Rechtschreibreglung §55.2; 
Sie muss nur hier nicht angewendet werden.