# Groß- und Kleinschreibung und Bindestrich bei Substantiv-Adjektiv-Zusammensetzungen

Tags: adjective, noun, spelling, hyphen

Werden zwei Substantive mit Bindestrich zusammengefügt, wie z. B. im *Druck-Erzeugnis,* werden beide großgeschrieben.
Bei zwei Adjektiven, wie z. B. *das deutsch-französische Wörterbuch,* werden beide kleingeschrieben.

Wie wird aber eine Kombination aus Substantiv und Adjektiv geschrieben?

Heißt es:

- > eine serverseitige Verbindung
- > eine Server-seitige Verbindung
- > eine server-seitige Verbindung

Welches ist die korrekte Schreibweise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Von der Seite des [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung):

> Regel 68:
>
> Auch in Zusammensetzungen und Aneinanderreihungen mit Bindestrich werden die Substantive großgeschrieben <§ 55 (2)>

Dabei wird das Beispiel

> Moskau-freundlich

genannt. Hiernach wäre Schreibweise 2 korrekt. Ist zwar etwas unglücklich, weil das ja ein Name ist, aber die Regel scheint für alle Substantive zu gelten.

Zweite hier relevante Regel:

> Regel 59:
>
> Zusammensetzungen mit einem Substantiv als erstem Bestandteil sind oft Verkürzungen von Wortgruppen. Es wird dabei ein Artikel oder eine Präposition (ein Verhältniswort) eingespart <§ 36 (1)>.

Beispiel:

> mondbeschienen (vom Mond beschienen)

Nach dieser Regel wäre Schreibweise 1 korrekt (serverseitig – von Seiten des Servers).

Dementsprechend geht 3 auf jeden Fall nicht, 1 oder 2 wären aber okay, je nachdem, ob man der Übersichtlichkeit halber einen Bindestrich setzen möchte oder nicht.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort und die Referenzierungen!

Comment: Für Eigennamen als ersten Bestandteil gibt es hier in der Tat eine gesonderte Regel – siehe meine Antwort. Die Sache ist etwas komplizierter bzw. interpretationsabhängig.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Danke fuer den Edit, hatte das mit den Formatierungen vergessen. Ich fand das Beispiel auch blöd da, aber so wie ich das sehe, kann man trotzdem finden, dass es ohne Bindestrich unübersichtlich ist, und einen setzen. Ich würd's auch generell ohne schreiben.

Answer (score 11):

Analog zu [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/10325/2594) ist das Wort auf jeden Fall zusammenzuschreiben und *serverseitig* auf jeden Fall zulässig.

Was, *Server-seitig* betrifft, so lautet § 45 [der offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf):

> Man kann einen Bindestrich setzen […] zur Gliederung unübersichtlicher Zusammensetzungen, zur Vermeidung von Missverständnissen […].

Aus den Beispielen wird ersichtlich, dass mit »unübersichtlichen Zusammensetzungen« Zusammensetzungen aus mehr als zwei Wörtern und mit »Missverständnissen« recht krasse Fälle wie *Druck-Erzeugnis* und *Drucker-Zeugnis* gemeint sind – was hier beides nicht vorliegt. Streng genommen ist die »Vermeidung von Missverständnissen« aber hinreichend schwammig, dass man damit auch *Server-seitig* als gerechtfertigt ansehen könnte.

Am Rande: § 51 erlaubt die Bindestrichsetzung zur Hervorhebung des ersten Teils, wenn dieser ein Eigenname ist, z. B. *Moskau-freundlich.*

Wenn wir nun vom Bindestrich ausgehen, bleibt noch die Frage der Groß- und Kleinschreibung. Hier greift § 55 (2):

> Die Großschreibung [von Substantiven] gilt auch für Substantive […] als Teile von Zusammensetzungen mit Bindestrich […]

Es wäre damit also *Server-seitig.*

---

Persönlich würde ich *serverseitig* empfehlen, da Großschreibung in erster Linie nützlich ist, um Substantive von anderem zu trennen und die Großschreibung eines Adjektivs damit aus dem Rahmen fällt – mal ganz abgesehen davon, dass es keiner extremen wörtlichen Auslegung der Rechtschreibregeln bedarf.

Comment: Welches Missverständnis kommt denn in Betracht bei 'serverseitig', das durch 'Server-seitig' vermieden werden könnte?

Comment: @userunknown: Naja, man kann sich immer auf den Standpunkt stellen, dass eine Wortfuge schwer zu erkennen ist, und ein Bindestrich behebt dieses Problem natürlich. Beachte, dass ich diese Meinung nicht vertrete, sondern nur darlege, wieso jemand sie vertreten könnte.

Comment: Kann man sie vertreten, ja oder nein? Wenn ja, dann müsste ein Missverständnis ausgeräumt werden. Wenn nicht dann nicht. Das man unsinnige Argumente vorbringen könnte - dem stimme ich zu. Du demonstrierst es. Es ist aber nicht nur ermüdend sondern provoziert selbst Mißverständnisse. Die Frage ist, welche Form richtig und welche falsch ist und richtig ist nur 'serverseitig'. Dieses ewige Getue dass das Richtige nur persönlicher Geschmack sei ist fehl am Platze.

Comment: Dass eine Wortfuge schwer zu erkennen sei ist übrigens weder thematisiert worden, noch empirisch belegt.

Comment: Ja, man kann diese Meinung vertreten, und zwar sogar in einer schlüssigen Argumentation – die allerdings auf einer äußerst wörtlichen Auslegung der Rechtschreibregeln beruht, welche ich nicht teile. Ich kann dies jetzt entweder unter den Tisch fallen lassen und einfach meine Meinung als richtig darstellen oder ich kann es der Vollständigkeit halber erwähnen, sodass sich der Fragende angesichts der Informationen selbst eine Meinung bilden kann. Dass die Regeln hier nur anhand von Beispielen darstellen was sie als missverständlich oder unübersichtlich einstufen, musst Du deren Autoren vorwerfen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Man kann sich gerade bei "Server-seitig" verstärkt auf den Standpunkt stellen, dass der Bindestrich dazu dient, nicht einfach nur eine "gewöhnliche" Wortfuge, sondern eine Wortfuge, die gleichzeitig den Wechsel zwischen englischer und deutscher Aussprache anzeigt, zu verdeutlichen. Es ist also durchaus eine Wortfuge, die ein wenig mehr Aufmerksamkeit verdient als andere Wortfugen. Deshalb empfinde ich "serverseitig" jetzt auch nicht unbedingt als das typischste Beispiel für dieses Thema.

Comment: @userunknown: »Dass eine Wortfuge schwer zu erkennen sei ist übrigens weder thematisiert worden, noch empirisch belegt.« – Also ich stolpere etwa einmal am Tag über eine Wortfuge, derentwegen ich das Wort ein zweites Mal lesen muss. Ich kenne ein Forum, das in einem 400-Beiträge-starken (nicht öffentlichen) Thread solche Wörter sammelt. Ich gehe davon aus, dass jedem, der meine Antwort liest, dieses Phänomen hinreichend bekannt ist, sodass es keines gesonderten Belegs bedarf.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: In der Tat. Allerdings bedarf diese Argumentation keiner deutlich weniger extremen Auslegung der Rechtschreibregeln als das typischste Beispiel, da keines der Beispiele zu den entsprechenden Regeln ansatzweise in diese Richtung geht.

Comment: a) Steht eine wörtliche Auslegung von Regeln einer sinngemäßen Auslegung gegenüber. Meine Auslegung ist sinngemäß und nicht spezifisch an einen Wortlaut geknüpft. Dieser Vorwurf ist also falsch. Zweitens kann man die Schwierigkeit "serverseitig" zu lesen nicht darauf stützen, dass irgendwo eine Liste mit 400 anderen Wörtern existitert oder dass Du über andere Wörter stolperst. Drittens erschließt sich nicht, inwiefern ein Bindestrich hilft "Server" als Wort englischsprachigen Ursprungs schneller zu identifizieren. Ältere Fremdwörter, die eingebürgert sind, werden auch ohne Bindestrich ...

Comment: ... geschrieben, etwa das Lederportemonaie, das Mailpostfach, die Browserweiche, der Photoapparat, reflexartig, impulsartig, routinemäßig, etatmäßig.

Comment: @userunknown: (1) Wo habe ich Dir bitte eine an den Wortlaut geknüpfte Auslegung der Regeln unterstellt? Ich stelle nur (wie Du) fest, dass eine wörtliche Auslegung einer sinngemäßen Auslegung gegenübersteht bzw. unter gewisen Bedingungen andere Ergebnisse produziert. (2) Doch, ich kann und meine Argumentation derartig stützen, wenn ich nicht Nachweise für Dinge erbringen möchte, wie dass der Himmel blau ist. Dass Du noch nie über eine Wortfuge gestolpert seist, würde ich Dir nicht abnehmen. (3) Nach welchem Kriterium?

Answer (score 4):

Das Wort *„serverseitig“* in *„serverseitige Verbindung“* ist kein Substantiv, sondern ein Adjektiv: Wie ist die Verbindung? Sie ist serverseitig. *„Serverseitig“* beschreibt die Verbindung genauer.

Da es sich um ein klassisches Kompositum handelt und hier keine Regelung für die Schreibung mit Bindestrich greift, schreibt man *„serverseitig“* klein und zusammen.

Die Schreibweise *„Server-seitig“* ist, um das hier zu erwähnen, inkorrekt, denn: Paragraph 55(2) der [Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/) besagt:

> Die Großschreibung gilt auch
>   (1) für nichtsubstantivische Wörter, wenn sie am Anfang einer Zusammensetzung mit Bindestrich stehen, **die als Ganzes die Eigenschaften eines Substantivs hat**

*„Serverseitig“* hat nicht die Eigenschaft eines Substantivs! Diese Eigenschaft hätte das Wort, wenn man es substantivisch gebrauchen werden würde: *„Das Serverseitige“*. In Kombination mit *„serverseitige Verbindung“* jedoch ist die Eigenschaft als Adjektiv gegeben. *„Verbindung“* ist hier das Substantiv.

Auch [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_seitig) weist mit Beispielen darauf hin:

- werkseitig
- nordseitig
- hausseitig
- ...
- serverseitig

Fazit: Lediglich die Schreibweise

> *„serverseitige Verbindung“*

ist korrekt.

Comment: Du zitierst nicht § 55(2), sondern § 55(1). Abgesehen davon stimme ich Deiner Argumentation nicht zu. Es ist richtig, dass § 55(1) nicht zutrifft, aber § 55(2) *trifft* zu, und erlaubt die Großschreibung mit Bindestrich. Siehe auch die Antwort von 
Wrzlprmft.

Answer (score 2):

```
serverseitig
```

Wird klein- und zusammengeschrieben, alles andere ist abseitig.

Die Wörterbücher sind voll von Bildungen mit ~seitig, die alle kleingeschrieben werden, teils mit Substantiven zusammengesetzt, teils mit anderem:

```
achtseitig
allseitig
ausgangsseitig
beiderseitig
beidseitig
diesseitig
ganzseitig
gegenseitig
hardwareseitig
kabelseitig
kundenseitig
linksseitig
sendekopfseitig
sensorseitig
steuerungsseitig
umseitig
vielseitig
wechselseitig
werksseitig
zweiseitig
```

Der Bindestrich ist eine Ausnahme und bedarf der besonderen Begründung. Die Tendenz dessen Gebrauch mehr und mehr zu tolerieren ist der ausschweifenden Argumentationslust hier geschuldet aber entspricht nicht den Standards. In Wahrheit ist die Antwort, was richtig ist, leicht und eindeutig.