# Mit Substantiv erweiterte Partizipien: Zusammen oder getrennt? Groß oder klein?

Tags: spelling, compound, capitalization, participle

Ich bin mir stets unsicher, was ich bei adjektivisch gebrauchten Substantiv-Partizip-Kombinationen mache. Welche der folgenden Schreibungen ist richtig?

> Er arbeitete in einem Metall verarbeitenden Betrieb.
>   Er arbeitete in einem Metall-verarbeitenden Betrieb.
>   Er arbeitete in einem metall-verarbeitenden Betrieb.
>   Er arbeitete in einem metallverarbeitenden Betrieb.

Comment: Ich sehe das nicht als Duplikat, weil wir hier kein Adjektiv haben,

Comment: Ah, um so besser :-)

Comment: @guidot *verarbeitend* als Partizip wird hier adjektivisch genutzt, und deswegen auch nach dem Betrieb gebeugt. Wie adjektivisch hättest du es gerne noch?

Comment: Hmm, jetzt hab ich gerade die Frage angepasst. Vielleicht warte ich lieber bis das geklärt ist.

Comment: Ich habe deinen Edit zurückgesetzt, weil *metallverarbeitend* ein Adjektiv ist, kein Partizip. *Verarbeitend* alleine wäre ein Partizip.

Comment: @Jan mit der Bitte um Erleuchtung: Wenn wir also ein Substantiv und ein Partizip zu einem Adjektiv zusammensetzen, in wiefern ist das eine Substantiv-Adjektiv-Zusammensetzung von der die duplikatsverdächtige Frage handelt?

Comment: @guidot Ein Partizip kann sich zu einem wortgleichen Adjektiv verwandeln. In *dem verarbeitenden Betrieb* ist *verarbeitend* kein Partizip mehr sondern ein Adjektiv. Mit *rennend* ist es vielleicht leichter zu verstehen: »**Rennend** kannst du ihn noch einholen« (Partizip; ersetzt »wenn du rennst«) versus »Der **rennende** Junge hat den Dieb gestellt.« (Adjektiv, flektierbar).

Comment: Also, Leute (insbesondere @Jan, die Schließer sind ja nicht pingbar), so geht's nicht; entweder muß die andere Frage so erweitert werden, daß sie (und die Antworten) auf die Besonderheiten von Partizipien eingehen, oder wir müssen diese Frage wieder öffnen (und sinnvollerweise auf solche Fälle einschränken).

Comment: @chirlu Ich möchte widersprechen. Entenregel. Es steht vor einem Substantiv wie ein Adjektiv. Es beugt sich durch die Fälle, Geschlechter und Numeri wie ein Adjektiv. Es wird kleingeschrieben, wie ein Adjektiv. Es kann mit *sein* nachgestellt werden, wie ein Adjektiv. Wenn etwas aussieht, watschelt und quakt wie eine Ente, ist es dann eine Ente? **Dass** ein Partizip zum Adjektiv werden kann, ist *nicht* auf Deutsch beschränkt, von dem her sehe ich keinen Grund eine künstliche Trennung herbeizureden, wo keine ist!

Comment: @Jan: Nun ist aber die Rechtschreibreform auf die (meiner Meinung nach dumme) Idee gekommen, Verbindungen "mit adjektivisch gebrauchten Partizipien" als syntaktische Fügungen aufzufassen. Künstlich oder nicht, sie verhalten sich jetzt orthographisch anders als gewöhnliche Adjektive. Nach der ursprünglichen Reformfassung von 1996 war sogar nur _Metall verarbeitend_ zulässig (aber _serverseitig_).

Comment: @chirlu: Das Problem war, dass die Frage eben nicht die Besonderheiten von Partizipien angesprochen hat, sondern allgemein nach Substantiv-Adjektiv-Verbindungen gefragt und auch nur Optionen zur Disposition gestellt hat, bei denen es keine Sonderregel für Partizipien gab. Hinzukommt, dass der Fragesteller die Frage weniger als eine Minute nach Eröffnung selbst als Duplikat markiert hat (aber aus irgendwelchen Gründen nicht selbst geschlossen hat). So oder so habe ich die Frage jetzt so umformuliert, dass sie nach Partizipien fragt, alle denkbaren Fälle beinhaltet und kein Duplikat mehr ist.

Comment: @chirlu... sonnengebräunt würde wohl kaum einer getrennt schreiben. Gilt diese Regel nur für's Partizip 1?

Comment: @Emanuel: Sie gilt dann, wenn man den vorderen Teil als selbständig (z.B. als Objekt des Partizips) aufgefaßt werden kann. Das dürfte beim Partizip II selten sein, geht aber auch beim Partizip I nicht immer (z.B. _freudestrahlend_).

Answer (score 3):

Nach meinem Pons ist die erste und letzte Möglichkeit korrekt.

> Kann das zusammengesetzte Partizip gleichermaßen als Zusammensetzung wie als syntaktische Fügung angesehen werden, schreibt man - je nachdem - zusammen oder getrennt.

Das findet sich auch in den Regeln des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung § 36 (2) und (2.1).

Folglich sind entweder

> Metall verarbeitend

oder

> metallverarbeitend

richtig.

Comment: Wie passt das zu der Duden-Regel 68, die in http://german.stackexchange.com/a/20033/3394 zitiert wird?

Comment: Es sind alle drei Möglichkeiten zugelassen, d.h. _metallverarbeitend_, _Metall-verarbeitend_ (nach der allgemeinen Regel, nach der zur Verdeutlichung einer Zusammensetzung der Bindestrich gesetzt werden kann) und _Metall verarbeitend_. Die letzte Version ist ein Überbleibsel der ersten Rechtschreibreform von 1996, das 2006 nicht vollständig zurückgenommen wurde.