# Zusammengesetzte Wörter als Adjektiv mit Bindestrich – Großschreibung?

Tags: compound, capitalization

Ich möchte zusammengesetzte Wörter generell mit Bindestrichen schreiben. Anders finde ich sie oft nicht lesbar. Das Nutzen von Bindestrichen ist für diesen Zweck erlaubt.

Nun frage ich mich, wie die Großschreibung bei Adjektiven gehandhabt werden soll.

Ein für mich unleserliches Beispiel:

> Insbesondere soll kein clienteigenes Backend erfordert sein.

Schreibe ich *Client-eigenes* oder etwa doch *client-eigenes?*

Comment: Duplikat von [Groß- und Kleinschreibung und Bindestrich bei Substantiv-Adjektiv-Zusammensetzungen (Adjektivierungen)](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20032/2594). (Ich schließe nicht, da ich eine Antwort auf jene Frage geschrieben habe, aber falls mir jemand zustimmt, bitte *Flag→duplicate* nutzen.)

Comment: warum schreibst du dann nicht "zusammen-gesetzt", "Binde-Strich" und "groß-Schreibung", wenn du das lesbarer findest?

Comment: @tofro weil dies gängige Wörter sind, die nicht primär als zusammengesetzt verstanden werden, sondern als eigene Wörter mit distinkter Bedeutung. "Generell" bedeutet nicht "immer".

Comment: **generell** (Adj.): *für die meisten oder alle Fälle derselben Art geltend, zutreffend*. Also mindestens zwei von drei ;)